In Filament, the pxlrbt-spotlight plugin doesn't show records
I recently installed the pxlrbt-spotlight plugin and I think it's amazing.
However, I'm encountering an issue with displaying records in the search list. Initially, the records were showing up in the search list similar to the Filament Global Search. But after setting shouldRegisterSpotlight() to false on some pages, the records disappeared. Even after undoing my changes, the records still don't appear. Currently, only the pages are displayed in the search results.
Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you!
enter image description here
I have added the needed methode to working with Filament global Search and is working fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
